# Finding the biggest number associated with the value in a dictionary

Tags: python

I am working on a dictionary that maps names to votes received. I need associate the name with the most votes, assigning it to the variable win.

So far:

```
vote = {}

for key in vote:
    vote(max(key)) = win
```

How do I associate win to the name, because I believe my error now is that I am associating it to the highest number.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question is very unclear: for one thing, the code won't do anything since the vote dictionary is empty, your assignment seems to be backwards (assigning `win` to `vote` instead of the other way around), and that isn't how you access a dictionary anyway. You need to work harder on your example.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way would be

```
win = max(vote, key=vote.get)
```

You could also use a Counter

```
from collections import Counter
win, = Counter(vote).most_common(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
win = sorted(vote, key=lambda x: votes[x])[-1]
```

More info here: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted

Comment: You can also use `key` with `min()` and `max()`. If you only need the max or the min, they are more efficient `O(n)` compared to sorting `O(n log(n))`